# Determine accessible Fragments at startup

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, android-productflavors

I am working on an Android app that has several different product flavors. Each flavor has a unique set of libraries it needs, but I don't have this information until runtime. Right now, all the features of the app are packaged into each product flavor, even if that flavor only uses a handful of them. What I would like to do is, at startup, determine which features can be accessed, and download the appropriate libraries it will need. Is there a way that I can determine at first startup which Fragments can be accessed by the Activity?

Comment: "download the appropriate libraries it will need" -- how do you plan to secure that? This sounds like a fine scenario for a code injection MITM attack. "Is there a way that I can determine at first startup which Fragments can be accessed by the Activity?" -- you can always use reflection to find subclasses of `Fragment` or some other base class or interface that you are using.

Comment: That's an intriguing point. Do you have any other recommendations for how to keep the app as concise as it can be, if I don't know how much it needs until runtime?

Comment: I'd go back a few steps and work on the "all the features of the app are packaged into each product flavor, even if that flavor only uses a handful of them" issue, so that this all gets resolved at build time.

Comment: I would love to, but I can't. One of the features the system sells itself on is that the client can just go to a website, and flip a boolean value to decide which features they'd like to include. They don't want to have to have a brand new release each time they change their mind on a feature.